# comunicate between 2 processes with stdin and stdout

Tags: python, subprocess

I would like to write a simple script (A) that executes an external script (B)

- A should communicate with B by writing to its stdin and reading its stdout
- B should read its stdin and print it

all this should be done without closing the stream

**A.py**

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'B.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for _ in range(3):
    process.stdin.write(b'hello')
    print(process.stdout.read())
```

**B.py**

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line)
```

the output should be:

```
>>> b'hello'
>>> b'hello'
>>> b'hello'
```

The problem is that A just waits in

```
print(process.stdout.read())
```

if I modify A, by adding close():

```
for _ in range(3):
    process.stdin.write(b'hello')
    process.stdin.close()
    print(process.stdout.read())
```

I get:

```
>>> b'hello\n'
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
>>>   File "A.py", line 7, in <module>
>>>     process.stdin.write(b'hello')
>>> ValueError: write to closed file
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Use [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

Python already has [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) method implemented (it goes to `A.py`, `B.py` is fine). However it's just suitable for simple communication (you know what data are you going to send up front), if you need a more complex one like:

```
send data to process B
read stdout
if stdout ...
    do something bases on stdout
    write to stdin
```

You have to implement your own `communicate()`, original implementation [here](https://github.com/certik/python-3.2/blob/master/Lib/subprocess.py#L788).

---

#### Step by step

I've tested and debugged this step by step and here is what happens:

```
# For Popen(bufsize!=0)
A: process.stdin.write(b'hello\r\n')
B: line = sys.stdin.readline() # Hangs
```

So after adding `bufsize=0` (unbuffered)

```
# Popen(bufsize=0)
A: process.stdin.write(b'hello\r\n') # Without \r\n B still hangs
B: line = sys.stdin.readline()
B: print('Send back', line.strip()) # Without strip it prints empty line
A: process.stdout.readline() # Hangs
```

So what works?

```
# Popen(bufsize=0)
A: process.stdin.write(b'hello\r\n')
B: line = sys.stdin.readline()
B: print('Send back', line.strip())
B: sys.stdout.flush()
A: process.stdout.readline()
```

---

#### Explained

You have *buffering* set to [`io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/io.html#io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE) (it's usually 4090B). From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> *bufsize* will be supplied as the corresponding argument to the io.open() function when creating the stdin/stdout/stderr pipe file objects: 0 means unbuffered (read and write are one system call and can return short), 1 means line buffered, any other positive value means use a buffer of approximately that size. A negative bufsize (the default) means the system default of io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE will be used.

So at first `A` won't flush because it hasn't filled its buffer yet and therefore `B` is waiting. It's [not possible to **simply** `process.stdin.flush()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2521054/1149736) under Windows, so you have to use `bufsize=0`.

Also writing [`os.linesep` (`\r\n`)](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/os.html#os.linesep) is important because of `readline()`.

***Note:*** I believe it should have worked also with `bufsize=1` (line buffering) but it didn't. I have no idea why.

Then the same happens in `B` when it won't flush `sys.stdout` and it surprises me, that `B:sys.stdout` is not set to *unbuffered* because:

> *bufsize* will be supplied as the corresponding argument to the io.open() function when creating the stdin/**stdout**/stderr pipe file objects

Anyway, you have to call `sys.stdout.flush()` in `B`.

It works with `close()` because it forces `flush()`.

---

#### *Gimme teh codes*

**A.py**:

```
import subprocess
import sys

process = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, r'B.py'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0)
for _ in range(3):
    process.stdin.write(b'hello\r\n')
    print(process.stdout.readline())
```

**B.py**:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print('Send back', line.strip())
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: after adding the \n it is still waiting as before

Comment: tried adding \r\n, unsuccessfully. when adding the flush, I get this error on the second iteration: IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: Wow, great answer and also works for me with a slight change, I flush after the write in A and not flush in B at all. I am using Python3.2, could this be the difference?

Comment: @OferHelman I'm running `Python 3.2.5 (default, May 15 2013, 23:07:10) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32` with windows 7, it can be version specific I think. I find it kind of magic to make these things work properly.

Comment: Interesting, very similar to my setup, I am adding the permutation that works for me in your answer

Comment: Simply put, open terminal run A.py ( specify location of B.py inside ) it hangs. Open new terminal , run B.py. It hangs. How does one test it.