# Clearing 'queued' characters from the command line

Tags: python, terminal

I'm writing a Python script in which at a certain point, the user is asked to enter a key combination (by simultaneously pressing those keys) and to confirm with enter. Grabbing the key combination and the enter key is done using the `keyboard` module and thus it works whether the command line is in focus or not. After that, an `input()` prompt is shown in which they need to enter some text.

The problem is that this input prompt gets 'skipped'. I assume this is because there are some characters and an enter stored which get entered into the `input` as soon as it appears.

How could I fix this? There's an `os.system('cls')` before the `input`, but that doesn't help. I've also tried adding a throwaway `input()` before the main prompt, this sort of worked but I'm looking for more of a general solution that also works if the characters aren't followed by an enter.

Comment: Would it be okay if you can provide the sample code?

Comment: @IceBear Added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, looks like I wasn't using the correct search term.
This function clears the input buffer on both Windows and UNIX:

```
def flush_input():
    try:
        import msvcrt
        while msvcrt.kbhit():
            msvcrt.getch()
    except ImportError:
        import sys, termios    #for linux/unix
        termios.tcflush(sys.stdin, termios.TCIOFLUSH)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38993222/)

Since I'm already importing the module at the top of my file and I only need Windows support for now, this is what I'm using:

```
def flush_input():
    while msvcrt.kbhit():
        msvcrt.getch()
```