# How Can I covert this method from C++ to Python?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, python-2.7, visual-c++

```
void resetInput() {
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); //discard input
}
```

The above code method is to reset inputs. I'm looking for a way to convert this into the Python method. Can someone please help me to do it?

Comment: This calls C++ specific API which do not have equivalent in python. Your code do not have enough context to do this conversion.

Comment: When an I/O error occurs in Python, it **raises** an `OSError` (IOError is an alias to OSError, these days).  There is no "error state" to clear.  Python's I/O stream's `readline` can be used to read-and-discard a line.

Comment: @Eljay this function is not for IO specific errors. This is used for handling errors when for example user type a word when program expected a number. Without knowing how he reads data from stdin in python code you can't tell what should be done.

Comment: I think this question is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520893/how-to-flush-the-input-stream-in-python