# How to clear buffer data? sys.stdin.flush does not work

Tags: python, buffer, stdin, sys

I want to know how can I make the buffer clean, from whatever it contains. I searched a little about it and some people say use `sys.stdin.flush` but it does not work.

```py
In [1]: import sys                                                                                                                                                              

In [2]: sys.stdin.read(1)                                                                                                                                                       
long long long string 1234567890
Out[2]: 'l'

In [3]: sys.stdin.read(1)                                                                                                                                                       
Out[3]: 'o'

In [4]: sys.stdin.flush()                                                                                                                                                       

In [5]: sys.stdin.read(1)                                                                                                                                                       
Out[5]: 'n'
```

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520893/how-to-flush-the-input-stream-in-python) might help.

Comment: @sj95126 thanks, but the solution is for windows, I'm using linux

Comment: Read further down, there's a Unix solution.

Comment: @AmirrezaRiahi did you read all the answers? Some don't use `msvcrt`